# Changing char(10) to char(3) grew table even after cleantable and shrinkfile

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

In a largely experimental attempt to reduce table space usage I altered a `char(10)` column to `char(3)`  (The column's contents are never more than three characters long)

Steps (Not carried out in a single batch)

```
use thedatabase;
alter table thetable
alter column thecolumn char(3) null

DBCC CLEANTABLE (thedatabase,'thetable', 500000); 
/* Apparently not needed for fixed length column but just in case*/

DBCC SHRINKFILE (1);
```

The operation completed successfully, but the table actually grew in size.    I know this can happen due to the way the sql engine modifies a column (creates a copy alongside and then copies the column contents) so I ran `dbcc cleantable` on the table, and then `dbcc shrinkfile` on the database file.  None of these operations made any difference to the table size.

The table has no index,  so not possible to run a rebuild index operation.

So my question is,  why did the table grow, even after commands to shrink it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has most likely to do with forwarded records, the new char(3) value is copied to a new allocation unit (page) leaving a forwarding pointer in its place. You can check if they exist like this.

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(ps.object_id) as TableName,
    i.name as IndexName,
    ps.index_type_desc,
    ps.page_count,
    ps.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
    ps.forwarded_record_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED') AS ps
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i
    ON ps.OBJECT_ID = i.OBJECT_ID  
    AND ps.index_id = i.index_id
-- WHERE forwarded_record_count > 0
   WHERE ps.object_id = object_id(<TABLENAME>)
```

The only way to fix this since you are on SQL Server 2005 would be to create a clustered index on the table and then to drop it. SQL 2008 would allows you to do `ALTER TABLE <TABLE> REBUILD`.

`DBCC CLEANTABLE` only cleans up variable length columns typed as `varchar` and `nvarchar`, see: [DBCC CleanTable](http://stevestedman.com/2013/05/dbcc-cleantable/) by Steve Stedman.